# Placing a button inside of a vue list item that redirects?

Tags: html, node.js, vue.js

I want to have a list of `v-list-item` with buttons inside of them, where clicking the button performs one action and clicking anywhere else in the list item redirects the user using `:to`. Visually everything looks fine, except when the user clicks the button, both the action and the redirection are performed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, doing `@click.prevent="handler"` on the button element fixes it.